Error in an argument using spectral theory
Let $Z=\sqrt{2}\mathbb Z$, and consider the sequence on $\mathbb{Z}$ $$\xi(k)= 1_{Z\cap [k,k+1]\neq\emptyset}.$$(remark that the intersection is either empty or with one point.)
Thanks to the comments, it is clear that this sequence is not periodic (@wojowu: the density of such $k$ goes to $1/\sqrt{2}$).
The problem is that it contradicts the following argument. Could you help me find where the error is below?
The basic idea is to consider $Z$ as a measure and write $\xi$ as the convolution $$\xi(k)=Z\star \psi(k)=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{x\in  Z}\psi(x-m)$$
where $\psi(y)=1_{[0,1]}(y)$.
One can prove in the right space that $\hat \xi=\hat Z\times \hat \psi$, and $\hat Z$ is purely atomic with Poisson summation formula. In particular, $\hat\xi$'s support is discrete, and this means with classical spectral theory (Helson, Szego, ...) that $\xi$ is periodic. I wrote all this down but I do not want to reproduce it here so that my mistake does not influence you.

No, this is a Sturmian word (in your example, the word is the fixed point of the morphism $0 \mapsto 1$ and $1 \mapsto 110$), and Sturmian words are not periodic, see e.g. Lothaire's book. Note that for $Z = \varphi \mathbb{Z}$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio, you get the famous Fibonacci word.

Thanks, I expected that. I am not a specialist of spectral theory and I would really need to understand how I use it wrong here.

An easy way to see this sequence is not periodic is that the density of $k$ for which $\xi(k)=1$ is equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Right, probably the fastest way, thanks
